# How to apply this pandas.Series code to compare several files within a folder

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, for-loop, dataframe

I already have this code that finds all the csv files in a folder and reads them in:

```
directory = os.fsencode(folderpath)
os.chdir(directory)
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        df1 = pd.read_csv(filename)[columnName]
```

Now I have code that can find all the rows that are found in every single csv file that I input:

```
    match = pd.Series(list(set(file1.columnName) & set(file2.columnName) & set(file3.columnName) & set(file4.columnName)))
```

How can I merge the two pieces of code above to find all the rows that are found in every single csv file within a folder and  return the matches in a single pandas dataframe?

Comment: It would be useful if you could show an example of such dataframes **and** what you expect the result to look like.  This sounds a lot like what I thought you meant in your last question.  Given your choice of accepted answer, I was obviously wrong about what I thought you meant last time.  It would be helpful for you to make it very clear as to what you are looking for by using an example that makes it obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create list of all `Series` first and then dynamically find matches by `reduce`:

```
#data from previous answer
vals = []
directory = os.fsencode(folderpath)
os.chdir(directory)
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        df1 = pd.read_csv(filename)['Name']
        vals.append(df1)

from functools import reduce
a = reduce(lambda x, y: set(x) & set(y), vals)
print (a)
{'Ben', 'Neil'}

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':list(a)})
print (df)
    col
0   Ben
1  Neil
```